# How to copy database from MySQL to another database using different python services, ensuring that a row gets copied only once?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database called tbltest which has 4 columns : Id, Fname, Lname, Iscategorized. I have to copy the data from its first three columns to another database tblcopy which has 4 columns: Id, Fname, Lname, Service_number. I copy the data only when Iscategorized is 0 and after copying, I update it to 1. The Service column tells the python service which is copying the data. Follwing is the code I use for copying using service 1.

```
import time
var = True
while var == True:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import MySQLdb
    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","amanbaweja","test" )
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltester\
       WHERE iscategorized = '%d'" % (0) + " limit 0,1 " 
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        id = row[0]
        fname = row[1]
        lname = row[2]
        iscategorized = row[3]
                # Now print fetched result
        print "id=%s,fname=%s,lname=%s,iscategorized=%s" % \
                 (id, fname, lname, iscategorized)

        cursor.execute('''INSERT into tblcopy (Id, Fname, Lname, Service_number) values(%s, %s, %s, %s)''',(id, fname, lname, "service1"))
        sql1 = "UPDATE tbltester SET iscategorized = 1 WHERE Id = '%s'" % id
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Now as my database is dynamically getting bigger and bigger, I am using multiple machines to run my python services. The python services are running together using *supervisor*. If I run 10 services with the above mentioned code,approximately 5 different entries get created in tblcopy as 5 python services get the same id at once. Is there any SQL method to solve my problem? Can we do this using stored procedure?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in parallelising this operation, as it is I/O bound: all `SELECT`'s and `INSERT`'s need to go through the same bottleneck, namely the database engine and the hard disk. This approach will actually be slower because you are now introducing concurrency issues.

Rewrite your (single-threaded) process like this:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM tbltester WHERE iscategorized = 0 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT into tblcopy
    SELECT id, fname, lname, "service1"
    FROM tbltester WHERE iscategorized = 0;
UPDATE tbltester SET iscategorized = 1 WHERE iscategorized = 0;
COMMIT;
```

It would be a different story if there was some significant (long-lasting) processing between your initial `SELECT` and your final `UPDATE`.

---

*This code was inefficient for several other reasons:*

- *the connection to MySQL is needlessly open and closed at each iteration (instead, open and close the connections outside of the loop)*
- *only one record is processed at a time (instead, process as many records at a time as possible)*
- *a transaction is started and committed at each iteration (instead, it may be acceptable to commit only every now and then, say every 10 iterations)*

*Also, it looks like there is an infinite `while` loop. If you want to have a "service" constantly copying data between tables, you might want to add a short delay inside your loop so as to avoid constantly hitting your database if there is nothing to process. Alternatively, and probably preferrably, you may want to look into [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html).*